# Dereferencing a pointer vs shifting for bytes?

Tags: c++, performance

I'm trying to improve performance for an application that does a lot of bit operations.

One operation is:

```
c |= (1 << i)
```

in which I want to set a single bit in a byte. I was thinking of maybe using a lookup table to get each of 8 values to OR in. Would an array access be faster or slower than just the original bit operation?

Or perhaps is there a better way?

Comment: Profile first, ask about optimisations later. Also, algorithmic improvements over micro-optimisations.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in such kind of operations and not in algorithm part?

Comment: I think any answer will be very dependent on architecture.

Comment: ARM, that would take around 2 cycles if i is a mutable, 1 if not.  Not counting register setup time nor assignment back to RAM or wherever.

Comment: Your code actually not set single bit. `c |= (1<<i)` would set, you do `c = c | (c<<i)`

Comment: @Lol4t0 Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Styne666, author edited post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On any modern computer architecture, the shift operation will complete in a single CPU cycle. A table lookup might take as little as one cycle if the table is in the CPU cache; otherwise it will take much, much longer (possibly millions of times longer, if the memory has been swapped to disk).

On older ARM processors (9 series and earlier), the shift takes two cycles (assuming `i` isn't a constant); in that case, a table lookup could be faster - a single cycle, if the table's base register is already set up, and the table is in the cache, and the processor has a cache at all.

Some very old processors didn't have fast shift hardware, in which case a lookup might be considerably faster - especially as CPU speeds tended to be the same as memory speeds back then.

So if you find yourself in the 1980s, or writing the firmware for a hard drive, then this might be useful; but make sure you measure it to be sure.

Comment: "If you find yourself in the 1980s".  Hehheheh

Answer (score 0):

Many architectures have a dedicated instruction for single bit set (or clear), which is substantially faster than the sequence (generate constant 1, shift it, bitwise-OR).  In that case, giving the compiler something it can recognize as replaceable with the bitset instruction is most important.

Using a lookup table is likely to prevent this optimization.

Stick with the simple code.  And look at the assembly produced by the compiler, it may surprise you.